# tcpdf if cell bigger than free space jump to new page

Tags: php, tcpdf

Hi i need a way to make content create in new page if it bigger than page free area
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS property `page-break-inside: avoid;` on an element will start it on the next page if it would otherwise be split by a page break. I have confirmed this property works with TCPDF.

Some example code:

```php
<?php

require_once('./tcpdf-master/tcpdf.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->AddPage();

$html = <<<EOD
<p style="page-break-inside: avoid;">This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. </p>
<p style="page-break-inside: avoid;">This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. </p>
<p style="page-break-inside: avoid;">This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. </p>
<p style="page-break-inside: avoid;">This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. </p>
<p style="page-break-inside: avoid;">This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. This is a long paragraph to test out the "page-break-inside: avoid" property. </p>
EOD;

$pdf->writeHTMLCell( 0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, false, true, 'C' );
$pdf->Output('page-break.pdf', 'I');
```

This will output a PDF like this:

[image: PDF with page-break-inside: avoid on the paragraphs]

Whereas without the  `style="page-break-inside: avoid;"` parts, it will output this:

[image: PDF without page-break-inside: avoid]

Comment: like this?
   $noteP="<p style='page-break-inside: avoid;'>$note</p>";
   $pdf->writeHTMLCell( 0, 0, '', '', $noteP, 0, 1, false, true, 'C'  );

Comment: @MuhammedRYHAN almost - TCPDF requires double quotes, so you would have to write: $noteP="<p style=\"page-break-inside: avoid;\">$note</p>"; in this case!

Comment: not working dude :/

Comment: @MuhammedRYHAN I've added example code to the answer along with example image outputs of what it does with and without the page-break-inside: avoid parts. Hopefully you can figure it what your current issue is with this!

Comment: thank you so much .... i found the solution already